# How can overlap QPushButton without applying layout on QGridLayout?

Tags: qt

How to place independently `QPushButton` without being affected by `QGridLayout` using Qt Designer if possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can always remove a widget from layout. But you have to take care of its geometry..

use `removeWidget(QWidget *widget)`.

Refer

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#removeWidget